# How to use a macro inside \includegraphics options?

Tags: macros, graphics, optional-arguments

I have to do several figures like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth]{./../ficherosComunes/images/capturaapp/01-actividadprincipal.png}
  \caption{Captura de pantalla de ActividadPrincipal.java}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth]{./../ficherosComunes/images/capturaapp/02-listadoficheros.png}
  \caption{Captura de pantalla de ActividadFicheros.java.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth]{./../ficherosComunes/images/capturaapp/03-listadoficherodetalles.png}
  \caption{Captura de pantalla de ActividadFicheroDetalles.java.}
\end{figure}
```

As it can be seen there's all times repeated `trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth` Would it be possible to write it in a variable? I have tried to define a `\newcommand{\texttrim}{trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth}` but it doesn't work if I put it as an option. I have also tried to define lengths (to have at least the trimming lengts defined) but they don't work either.

Comment: A hint: You can use `\graphicspath{{./../ficherosComunes/images/capturaapp/}}` to add your image folder to the search scope and then use `\includegraphics{01-actividadprincipal}`. Furthermore you can omit the suffix `.png` since `graphicx` finds the right extension automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that file was just a testing one before inserting the code in the final document (another .tex) for quick compilation. In the final one I use the graphicspath already. And about the extension I got used to use it as in some images I have some .svg that I converted into .pdf, as pdflatex doesn't support .svg, with the same name. But yes, maybe I should omit the extension except in those especial cases

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

### 1. define a new command

(as carsten said already)

```
\newcommand{\trimmedgraphic}[2][]{%
    \includegraphics[trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm,clip,width=1\textwidth,#1]%
        {#2}%
}
```

You can define the command with an optional argument to be able to pass additional options to `\includegraphics`. You may add the `{figure}` stuff if you like.

### 2. define a command to preset the keys

```
\newcommand{\settrimming}{%
    \setkeys{Gin}{%
        trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm,clip=true,
        width=\textwidth,
    }
    \presetkeys{Gin}{clip}{}
}
```

If you use `\settrimming` all following graphics will be trimmed. You can use it in the preamble (then you can use the definition directly and there's no need to wrap it in `\settrimming`) or you use it inside a group (like `{figure}` env) to scope its effect. Note that you'll need to load `xkeyval.sty` for this way.

### 3. using `\edef` and `\expandafter`

```
\edef\trimoptions{trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm, clip,width=1\textwidth}
```

You can use `\edef` to store the options an then make it usable in the option list by adding two `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\trimoptions]{example-image}
```

### full MWE example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}% necessary for \presetkeys
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\trimmedgraphic}[2][]{%
    \includegraphics[trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm,clip,width=1\textwidth,#1]%
        {#2}%
}

\newcommand{\settrimming}{%
    \setkeys{Gin}{%
        trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm,clip=true,
        width=\textwidth,
    }
    \presetkeys{Gin}{clip}{}
}

\edef\trimoptions{trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm, clip,width=1\textwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[trim = 1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm, clip,width=1\textwidth]%
            {example-image}
        \caption{Normal figure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \trimmedgraphic{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure using trimmedgraphic}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \trimmedgraphic[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Figure using trimmedgraphic}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \settrimming
        \includegraphics{example-image-c}
        \caption{Figure using settrimming}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\trimoptions]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure using edef and expandafter}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could define the whole thing as one command, taking the figure details as arguments, like this

```
\newcommand\myfigure[2]{%
 \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[trim = 9.55cm 1.8cm 10.25cm 4.05cm, clip,width=1\textwidth]%
    {#1}
    \caption{#2}
 \end{figure}%
}
```

and then simply call it like this

```
\myfigure{./../ficherosComunes/images/capturaapp/01-actividadprincipal.png}{Captura de pantalla de ActividadPrincipal.java}
```