# Storing my 'standard float alignment' in a macro

Tags: macros, floats, expansion

While writing a few macros to wrap around float environments, I stumbled upon failure of macro-expansion (at least I think so) when it comes to storing float specifiers.

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{myfig}

\begin{document}
\section{Dummy section}

%\begin{myfig}[b!]
\begin{myfig}
  Yadda yadda yadda
\end{myfig}

\end{document}
```

`myfig.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myfig}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@std@float@align}{p!}
%\newenvironment{myfig}[1][t!]{
\newenvironment{myfig}[1][\@std@float@align]{
  \begin{figure}[#1]
}{
  \end{figure}
}
\makeatother
```

When compiling with `xetex`, this gives me:

```
./main.tex:10: LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `\'.
```

I tried getting it to work with the strategy proposed in 3. of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127926/124619), trying to [understand `tex` expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/when-to-use-edef-noexpand-and-expandafter). Judging from me posting this question, I failed. How do I get to store my float specifier in a macro and use it?

Comment: Try `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\begin{figure}[#1]}\x`. If you have a recent enough (later than TeXLive 2019) XeTeX, then `\expanded{\noexpand\begin{figure}[#1]}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it! Can you elaborate what caused the failure and how you fixed it?

Comment: in addition to Phelype's comment you are missing `%` from ends of lines so your definitions have unwanted space tokens, but as I note in the answer below you do not need the redefinition at all here.

Comment: @tillyboy The error happens because the optional argument of floating environments treat the argument as a string, so `\foo` is ``\`` `f` `o` `o`, and not whatever `\foo` expands to. Using `\edef` (or `\expanded`) like that expands everything (except for `\begin`, which is prefixed with `\noexpand`) and then starts the figure with `\@std@float@align` expanded. Though David's suggestion of redefining `\fps@figure` is the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `!` routinely. `!` means *ignore* the (user specified) constraints on float placement. So it is better to set constraints that you want rather than always ignoring the constraints.

The default figure placement is `\fps@figure`

So to make the default be `b` you just need

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fps@figure{b}
\makeatother
```

There is no need to redefine the figure environment.

Comment: I use the `!` for testing purposes, to get more robust results ;) Is there something like `\fps@float` that affects all floats (including newly defined ones)?

Comment: @tillyboy even for testing using a default of "ignore the defaults" means you are testing the wrong thing.  latex itself doesn't have a float definition command, but if you are using the float package you specify the default placement when defining the float as 2nd argument to `\newfloat`